# Lambda Provisioned Concurrency in CloudFormation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, serverless

Note: Please read my question before flagging it as it is different from many other Provisioned Concurrency questions I've seen on SO.

I need to configure provisioned concurrency in one of my existing applications that uses **CloudFormation** templates with Lambda functions (`AWS::Lambda::Function` resource, **NOT** SAM with `AWS::Serverless::Function` resource).

I did some tests but here's where I am stuck right now:

**Provisioned concurrency can only be configured for `Alias` or `Version` however...**

- It can't be configured for `Alias` that points to the `Live` function, it must point to a `Version`
- It can't be configured for `Version` that is the `$LATEST`

**So what's the "right" way to setup Provisioned concurrency?**

When deploying CloudFormation template, I can create a `Version` resource which can have provisioned concurrency configured (shown below). The API Gateway endpoint can directly point to this specific `Version` instead of the `$LATEST` version.

However, there is no way to update `Version` resource. Once it's created, it can only be deleted.

So each time I update my lambda function code, I would have to manually remove the current `Version` resource from CloudFormation and add a new one so it can create a new `Version`. This defeats the purpose of having template to deploy.

What are my other options? How can I have a Lambda function ($LATEST, Version or Alias) that has

1. provisioned concurrency configured
2. I can make changes to Lambda code without having to modify CloudFormation template each time.

```yaml
  
  ######## LambdaTest Function ########
  LambdaTest:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    DependsOn:
      - LambdaRole
      - LambdaPolicy
    Properties:
      FunctionName: "LambdaTest"
      Role: !GetAtt LambdaRole.Arn 
      Code:
        S3Bucket: !Ref JarFilesBucketName
        S3Key: LambdaTest.jar
      Handler: com.example.RnD.LambdaTest::handleRequest
      Runtime: "java11"
      Timeout: 30
      MemorySize: 512

  ####### LambdaTest Function Version ########
  LambdaTestVersion:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Version"
    Properties:
      FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaTest.Arn
      Description: "v1"
      ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig: 
        ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 5
```

Comment: Probably without a custom resource you can't do that. So you need to program a lambda function which would act as a custom resource in your cloud formation, and do all the updates to versions, etc. using AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

While you are correct, we cannot use `$LATEST` alias per AWS. I also think you are missing some key pieces of information, that SAM usually generates the Lambda, let me try and share what I did.

First, just FYI - `SAM generates the Lambda resources that you are seeking, as part of its process`. Now if *you want to go directly/manually/create the lambda resources, sure you can*, then you will have to ***wire up the `AutoPublishAlias: live`***.

---

Second part, in the picture (AWS SDK) is the actual solution on deploying live parts.

> #### My solution/workaround is to perform an `AutoPublishAlias: live` in the *function preference*

[image: AWS SAM Serverless Lambda and functions AutoPublishAlias: live]

##### you can just add that per the ref, or follow the steps below and compare/copy/paste what the SAM file gave you vs the AWS Lambda file has

---

Optional for your help -->

1. Select `Add configuration`, with provisioned Concurrency enabled for a specific Lambda function version or alias (but you can’t use `$LATEST`).

Since you can have different settings for each version of a function. Using an alias, it is easier to enable these settings to the correct version of your function.

2. `Select the alias live` ,
   note: that
   *you will have to* keep that updated to the latest version using the AWS SAM `AutoPublishAlias` function preference.
3. Then go to the Provisioned Concurrency, use something like 500 and Save.
4. Now -> Provisioned Concurrency configuration is in progress and all execution environments are ready to handle the inbound concurrent requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
LambdaTestVersion:
Type: "AWS::Lambda::Version"
Properties:
  FunctionName: !GetAtt LambdaTest.Arn
  Description: "v1"
  AutoPublishAlias: live
  AutoPublishAliasAllProperties: true     
  ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
    ReservedConcurrentExecutions: !Sub 'Some SSM pram path'
```